# Массив textView

Tags: java, android, массивы, textview, android-textview

Имеется `activity` в котором есть 3 текстовых поля: `textView`, `textView2`, 
`textView3`. Цель установить каждому `textView` соответствующее значение из массива (Вывожу список пользователей).

```
public class show_users   {

    private TextView textView;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_user);

        textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        for (int i=0; i<3; i ++){   
            textView.setText(array[i].echo_users()); 
        }
```

В последней строчке кода я просто использую `textView`, а хотелось бы реализацию, где будет использоваться нечто похоже на `textView[i]`. Пробовал с массивами делать, не получается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как то так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_user);

    textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    fillTextViews(array, textView, textView2, textView3);
}

private void fillTextViews(MyObject[] array, TextView... textViews) {
    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
        textViews[i].setText(array[i].echo_users());
    }
}
```

где `TextView...` это синтаксическая конструкция эквивалентная `TextView[]`, то есть массиву, но с тем исключением что при вызове метода с таким параметром мы можем вместо массив указать сразу его элементы как будто это отдельные параметры метода.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает как часы)

Comment: Алексей, по этой проблеме можете помочь?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532225/unable-to-instantiate-application