# Unable to instantiate application

Tags: java, android

Переименовал классы в проекте, был выполнен рефакторинг. Затем запуская проект стала появляться ошибка:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

Переименовал классы обратно как было, был выполнен рефакторинг. Теперь приложение не запускается, но уже с другой ошибкой.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:134)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4123) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:134) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Помогите решить проблему, знаний не хватает её решить. 
И так и так ошибка возникает

Comment: Потерялся класс  `com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication`.
Посмотрите, есть ли у Вас в пакете такой класс. Импортируется ли он вообще?

Comment: Главный класс в файле главного класса посмотрите как называется. Может имена не совпадают. Вы же файлы переименовали, а их содержимое - не забыли?

Comment: Класс нигде не импортируется. Если я правильно понял где смотреть, то в папке app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication где все классы содержаться. Имена везде совпадают вроде же, ведь я теперь даже если обратно их переименовываю другая ошибка совершенно возникает(( Угробил курсач называется. Сейчас новый проект создал и пытаюсь всё туда перекопировать, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Проверьте файлы на совпадение их (файлов) имён с именами классов, описанных в них.

Comment: Вообщем так и не получилось ничего, но банально сделал другой проект и все классы и активити перекопировал. Всё заработало. Старый проект забуду как страшный сон. Спасибо большое за то что откликнулись в любом случае!)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать `rebuild project`, если не помогло, попробуйте отключить `Instant Run`
<kbd>Settings</kbd>-><kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd>-><kbd>Instant Run</kbd> Снять первую галочку

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло. Кстати говоря новый проект создал всё туда перекопировал и заработало. Есть смысл инстант ран обратно галочку ставить? Или пусть на будущее так и останется?

Comment: Нет, в некоторых случаях это помогает избежать проблем связанных с базами данных библиотек. Как realm, sugar